# Are there IMDb datasets with IMDb ID numbers and actor birthdates?

Tags: data-request, data-format, film

1. I want datasets that have the name of the movie and its link on the site or the tt-number.
   E.g. for Jurassic Park (1993) it would be in the format:

> ```
> > NAME                     ID           LINK
> > Jurassic Park (1993)     0107290      http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107290/
> ```

2. The datasets of actors contain no birthdates, at least not in the ones I can find on `ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/`.

Does anyone know how to get those?

Please note: I do NOT want those general imdb datasets!
But instead I want ones that have the above mentioned characteristics.

Answer (score 4):

1) I would like to point you to a dataset and an API that provides IMDB information.

Here are some queries to get the information from your example, and to show you what kind of data to expect from the dumps.

- [Get the imdb_id (generic) of a movie, given the movie's name](http://u01.unigraph.rocks/?q=%7B%0A++subjects(property%3A+%22label%22%2C+text%3A+%22Jurassic+Park%22%2C+lang%3A+%22en%22)+%7B%0A++++uid%0A++++label.en%0A++++url%0A++++imdb_id+%40propagate%0A++++instance_of(filter%3A+%22%240+%3D%3D+%6012f923b0%60%22)+%40propagate%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A):

You can either query for that information like shown or download one of:

- a) [The entire Unigraph datadump](http://data.unigraph.rocks/20170227185558/)
- b) a slightly [smaller subset](http://data.unigraph.rocks/20170307185516/) comprising of only:

  - Wikidata
  - Freebase
  - Geonames
  - OurAirports and
  - EDGAR data

You can read more about the dumps and their structure [here](https://github.com/unigraph/docs/wiki/Datadump).
The IMDB arrives through Wikidata and Freebase, not through IMDB directly.

As for the url on the site, if it is not part of the url: [] in the response you will have to append it like so: http://www.imdb.com/title/ + imdb_id (provided the id starts with "tt" (for movie).

2) [Actors with birth dates](http://u01.unigraph.rocks/?q=%7B%0A++subjects(property%3A+%22label%22%2C+text%3A+%22Brad+Pitt%22%2C+lang%3A+%22en%22)+%7B%0A++++uid%0A++++date_of_birth%0A++++label.en%0A++++url%0A++++imdb_id+%40propagate%0A++++instance_of(filter%3A+%22%240+%3D%3D+%6012f97bdf%60%22)+%40propagate%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A), again you might have to append the url. This time like so: http://www.imdb.com/name/ + imdb_id

Hope this answers your question.

*Disclaimer: I am building Unigraph*

Comment: Not bad, and it's nice that the linked data dump is free, but, long-term, unigraph appears to be commercial, and, if you start at data.unigraph.rocks, there's no current path to the data dump?

Answer (score 0):

[MovieLens](http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/) dataset includes over 40000 popular movies and contains their IMDB and [TheMovieDB](http://themoviedb.org) IDs. TheMovieDB itself offers API to get IMDB ids and other information.